# ASP.NET MVC with WCF, cache notification issue

Tags: asp.net, wcf, caching

I've got a WCF which provides data to my asp.net app. I want to cache this data in application but I don't know is there a ready mechanism to make dependency notifications.

In details I need something like this:

- WCF returns data
- Client gets this data and put into the cache
- Now client returns data from its cache
- Suddenly data in WCF is changed
- Client gets notification(?) and fill cache again with fresh data

If there is no ready mechanism, how would you solve that?

Comment: When you say 'data in WCF is cached', did you mean 'data in WCF is *changed*'?

Comment: yes, sorry about that, should be: changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you need here is a custom CacheDependency object that calls the WCF service every *n* seconds (where *n* is an acceptable amount of latency) and compares with the previous result to see if the data is updated. Your custom dependency can then call its' `NotifyDependencyChanged` method, which tells ASP.NET that the underlying data has changed and the cached object is stale. There's a tutorial on creating a custom CacheDependency object [here](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cND87IlQ9WMC&pg=PA481&lpg=PA481&dq=custom%2bcache%2bdependency&source=bl&ots=TSfH1sHw7b&sig=_PILUBm1TRfy0Nr2ZJXYKrEf4II&hl=en&ei=w0QASvDZKYb6_AawzYDzBg&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=custom%2bcache%2bdependency&f=false).

I *think* your custom CacheDependency would look something like this (untested code):

```
/// <summary>
/// DTO for encapsulating stuff needed to create the dependency
/// </summary>
public class WebServiceCacheDependencySetup
{
    public object serviceClient { get; set; }
    public string clientMethod { get; set; }
    public int pollInterval { get; set; }
}

/// <summary>
/// Generic web services cache dependency
/// </summary>
public class WebServiceCacheDependency : CacheDependency
{
    private Timer timer;
    private static string previousHash;

    private object client;
    private string clientMethod;

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructor for the cache dependency
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="setup">Object that specifies how to create dependency and call the dependent web service method</param>
    public WebServiceCacheDependency(WebServiceCacheDependencySetup setup)
    {
        // Create a timer with a specified poll interval
        timer = new Timer(CheckDependencyCallback, this, 0, setup.pollInterval);

        client = setup.serviceClient;
        clientMethod = setup.clientMethod;

        previousHash = string.Empty;
    }

    public void CheckDependencyCallback(object sender)
    {
        // Reflect on the service's proxy to find the method we want to call
        Type clientType = client.GetType();
        MethodInfo method = clientType.GetMethod(clientMethod);

        // Programmatically invoke the method and get the return value
        object returnValue = method.Invoke(client, null);

        // Cast the return to a byte array so we can hash it
        Byte[] returnBytes = (Byte[])returnValue;

        using (SHA512Managed hashAlgorithm = new SHA512Managed())
        {
            // Hash the return value into a string
            Byte[] hashedBytes = hashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(returnBytes);
            string hashedValue = Convert.ToBase64String(hashedBytes);

            // Compare the new hash to the last hash
            if (hashedValue != previousHash)
            {
                // If the hashes don't match then the web service result has changed
                // so invalidate the cached object
                NotifyDependencyChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);

                // Tear down this instance
                timer.Dispose();
            }
        }

    }

    protected override void DependencyDispose()
    {
        if (timer != null)
        {
            timer.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```